# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` that I add at run time. I need the items of the first  `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to stay the same in all the rows of the `GridView` but I want the items of the second `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to be different from row to another depending on the selected item of the first `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

If we say the first `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` represents the locations and the second `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` represents the sublocations. So, I want the second `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` items to be the sublocations of the selected location from the first `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Like this if `Canada` is selected

```
Country(comboBoxItems)  |     State/Province(ComboBox Items)
USA                           Quebec
CANADA(selected)              Ontario
ENGLAND                       Manitoba
                              Alberta
```

Then if you select `USA`

```
Country(comboBoxItems)  |     State/Province(ComboBox Items)
USA (Selected)                California
CANADA                        New York
ENGLAND                       Montana
                              Ohio
```

Comment: Punctuation is your friend. The clearer your question is the more likely some one will take the time to read it. I scanned this twice and I still don't know what the question is.

Comment: I agree with BW. Ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Recap of your problem:

You have a collection of data and want to filter on it.

This is a question with the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147049/how-to-apply-a-filter-on-linqtosql-results/13184592#13184592) that extends on this subject a bit more. (To be specific, filter a LINQtoSQL IQueriable object before it is fired to the database.)

I found two solutions that might be interesting for our problem.

I found a way to do it for data in DataSets (ADO.NET)

```
DataTable source { get; set; }
String ValueMember { get; set; }
String DisplayMember { get; set; }
String FilterMember { get; set; }

Object ADOSelect(Object criterium)
{
    if ((source == null) || (criterium == null)) return null;

    return
    (
        from r in source.AsEnumerable()
        where (r[FilterMember] == criterium)
        select new
        {
            Value = r[ValueMember],
            Display = r[DisplayMember]
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

And a more generic solution.

```
class Record
{
    public object Display { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Object> source { get; set; }
String ValueMember { get; set; }
String DisplayMember { get; set; }
String FilterMember { get; set; }

Object DataSelect(Object criterium)
{
    List<Record> result = new List<Record>();
    foreach (var record in source) Parse(sender, record, criterium, result);
    return result;
}

private void Parse(object record, Object criterium, List<Record> result)
{
    MethodInfo DisplayGetter = null;
    MethodInfo ValueGetter = null;
    bool AddRecord = false;

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in record.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.Name == DisplayMember) DisplayGetter = property.GetGetMethod();
        else if (property.Name == ValueMember) ValueGetter = property.GetGetMethod();
        else if (property.Name == FilterMember)
        {
            MethodInfo ExternalGetter = property.GetGetMethod();
            if (ExternalGetter == null) break;
            else
            {
                object external = ExternalGetter.Invoke(record, new object[] { });
                AddRecord = external.Equals(criterium);
                if (!AddRecord) break;
            }
        }
        if (AddRecord && (DisplayGetter != null) && (ValueGetter != null)) break;
    }

    if (AddRecord && (DisplayGetter != null) && (ValueGetter != null))
    {
        Record r = new Record();
        r.Display = (DisplayGetter != null) 
            ? DisplayGetter.Invoke(record, new object[] { })
            : null;
        r.Value = (ValueGetter != null) 
            ? ValueGetter.Invoke(record, new object[] { })
            : null;
        result.Add(r);
    }
}
```